# 3.5" touchscreen, tkinter output only?

Tags: tkinter

I am currently working on a project for which I am using a 3.5" touchscreen as an output for some buttons. I can get it to be used as the output for the whole GUI, but that leads to the display being overcrowded and an inability to use the monitor for other functions as I would like. Any advice on how to just output a tkinter window to the touchscreen?

Comment: If you are using an Adafruit touchscreen, you can use PyGame to write to the display. See [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/pitft-pygame-tips)

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("TouchScreen Window")
window.geometry('800x600')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [MagPi Magazine issue #29](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/29/) which has the basics for getting a TkInter window running.